# How to continue webdriver/selenium after error

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm doing a test bot with webdriver. I have a scenario where it clicks on a button, a new windows open, and it searches for an element by a specific xpath, but sometimes there is no such element because it can be disabled and i get this error: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException. How can i bypass it/continue the bot so it just closes the new windows if it doesn't find the element with that xpath and just continue with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java :

```
List<WebElement> foundElement = driver.findElements(By.xpath("<x-path of your element>"));
if (foundElement.size() > 0) 
{
    // do whatever you want to do in **presence** of element
} else {
    // do whatever you want to do in **absence** of element
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to surround the click event with a try/catch statement, and inside the catch statement check if the exception is the one you are trying to bypass:

```
try {
    driver.findElement(by).click();
} catch(Exception e) {
    if ( !(e instanceof NoSuchElementException) ) {
       throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: re-throwing the exception will still stop OP's execution. He wants continue from that point. Maybe log/print the exception instead of re-throwing.

Comment: The exception is only re thrown where the exception is not an instance of NoSuchElementException, but yes, he can ignore all exceptions that he wants