# Selenium WebDriver - Catch failure and continue with next step

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Selenium WebDriver with multiple test steps which are divided as the following:

```
    //Example Test Step 1
    driver.get("https://url.de");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys("username");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login-wrapper > input.button")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Your account")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.link")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("items_1")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("items_2")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='items_1'])[1]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@value='delete it'])[1]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.button.auth")).click();
    System.out.println("[x] Test step has been performed sucessfully: ABO KUNDE");
```

If one test step fails, I want to catch this exception and force Selenium to continue with the next step. How can I handle this and do I have to define this handling for every single step?

So for example, the test step

```
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");
```

fails. Can I force Selenium to continue with "Example Test step 2"? We are using the Selenium WebDriver with BrowserStack.

Comment: Correct your title. You are using Selenium WebDriver, not Selenium IDE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to continue webdriver/selenium after error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37399391/how-to-continue-webdriver-selenium-after-error)